# Add a request filter to Spring which supports Rest resource annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My Spring web app is configured via Java annotations (see the configuration class at the bottom).

Is it possible to add a request filter in front of one controller (or possibly many via some sort of configuration) that supports the same (or at least a subset of the) annotations available inside `@RestController` methods, such as `@PathVariable`, `@RequestParam`, etc.?

So far I found the documentation about the [HandlerInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) interface within the [DispatcherServlet Interception docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) and I configured one following what's  in [Interceptors configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-interceptors):

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(ctx.getBean(CustomInterceptor.class));
}
```

But the interceptor implements the `HandlerInterceptor` interface thus the `preHandle()` method has a given signature:

```
preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
```

I can of course read parameters, header values, etc from the arguments, but I was wondering whether some other way was already supported.

That the filter shows up in some sort of documentation (I'm using [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) and [SpringFox](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/)) would be a plus.

---

### Main config class

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@ComponentScan(basePackages= { /* ... */ })
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class WebappConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        // extra Jackson configuration
    }

    // see below for this method
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(ctx.getBean(CustomInterceptor.class));
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you looked into spring security? Spring security attaches a chain of filters before the request arrives at the controller. You can configure spring security either as java based config or xml based config. All you have to do is add a bean named springSecurityFilterChain in your web.xml which serves as a entry point to DelegatingFilterProxy

Comment: Hows about RequestBodyAdvice with @ControllerAdvice(RestController) you can read all the parameters here.

Comment: @22kar I don't know know Spring Security: are you suggesting to look inside its code, or to use it in my application?